# Älter als Autos

Tags: phrase-request

Wenn man auf Englisch eine Figur in einem Roman sagen lässt: "I am older than cars", dann entsteht beim Leser die Vorstellung eines Wesens, das schon existiert hat, bevor es Autos gab. Wenn man dagegen auf Deutsch schreibt: "Ich bin älter als Autos", dann klingt das nicht nur merkwürdig, sondern lässt mich außerdem denken, dass jemand älter ist, als die Autos, die hier auf dem Parkplatz stehen.

Wie drückt man diesen Gedanken besser aus?

---

Re: Missverständnisse

Ein Wesen, das älter als Autos ist, ist ganz offensichtlich kein Mensch, denn kein Mensch kann so alt werden, dass er im Jahr 2018 älter als die 1800-irgendwas erfundenen Autos ist. Es geht in dieser Frage also um übernatürliche Wesen!

Aber euer Missverständnis macht gerade das Problem deutlich, das ich habe. Auf Englisch ist der Satz nämlich nicht missverständlich. Die englische Wendung macht ganz klar, dass jemand unerwartet alt ist, älter als er eigentlich sein kann.

Stellt euch einen Menschen vor, der jemandem begegnet, der wie ein Mensch aussieht, dann aber sagt: Ich bin älter als du denkst. Ich bin älter als die Felsen hier. Nur eben nicht mit Felsen (wo jeder sofort versteht, wie das gemeint ist), sondern mit Bäumen oder etwas anderem, wo die individuellen Objekte auch jünger als ein Mensch sein können.

> I am older than trees = Ich habe schon vor dem ersten Baum existiert (vor Millionen Jahren)
>   I am older than these trees = Ich bin älter als diese Bäume (gepflanzt 2006)

Comment: Die Autos auf dem Parkplatz wären aber bestimmte Autos, also nur gemeint bei "Ich bin älter als die Autos". Wenn nicht eben von einem bestimmten Auto die Rede war oder eine Geste auf ein bestimmtes zeigt, kann man auch sagen "Ich bin älter als das Auto".

Comment: Soo alt sind Autos nicht. Ich denke, der englische Ausdruck *cars* meint hier nicht *Autos* (automobiles), sondern *Wagen*, also Kisten mit zwei bis vier Rädern, ohne Bestimmung der Antriebsform. Anders kann ich mir dieses Idiom nicht erklären.

Answer (score 2):

Beim Altersvergleich mit dem Autowesen würden Menschen tatsächlich 'alt aussehen', da das erste Auto nach heutigem Verständnis (und je nach Interpretation) 1886 gebaut wurde (ein 'Benz') und der Mensch mit nachgewiesenermaßen höchstem erreichtem Lebensalter 122 Jahre alt wurde (Jeanne Calment, sie starb 1997 mit 122 Jahren). Man müsste dann einen anderen Vergleich wählen - und sich vorher absichern, da oft ein Smartphone in Reichweite ist, mit dem sich solche locker in den Raum geworfenen Vergleiche leicht überprüfen lassen.

Wenn man sich auf ein konkretes Autoindividuum oder auf einen bestimmten Computer oder auf eine Gruppe von ihnen bezieht, könnte man sagen

> Ich bin älter als dieser Computer / als jeder Computer hier im Raum.

Ich bin nicht sicher, ob der generalisierende Artikel 'der' in dem Satz '*ich bin älter als der Personal Computer*' (englisch auszusprechen) immer richtig interpretiert würde. Man könnte aber auch sagen

> Mich gibt's schon länger als das Internet / als das Smartphone  / als
> Smartphones.

oder

> Mich gab's schon, bevor das Smartphone erfunden wurde.

Etwas umständlich könnte man auch ausholen zu

> Ich wurde zu einer Zeit geboren, als es noch keine ... gab.

oder

> Ich stamme aus einer Zeit, da war 'Made in Germany' noch gleichbedeutend mit 'gut'.

Oft bezieht sich der Vergleich auf eine angesprochene Person:

> Mich gab's schon, als du noch in den Windeln gelegen hast.
>
> Ich wurde zu einer Zeit geboren, als du noch mit Legos gespielt hast.

Über das Alter des Gesprächspartners zu spekulieren, ist spätestens in den mittleren Jahren nicht mehr so furchtbar interessant, aber junge Leute tun das gerne. Früher gab es mal einen Spruch, der vielleicht heute noch benutzt wird. Wenn jemand gefragt wurde: 'Und, wie alt bist du?' kam immer die Antwort

> 'So alt wird kein Schwein',

zu verstehen als '*so alt wie ich werde, wird kein Schwein*.'

Es hat lange gedauert, bis ich verstanden hatte, was damit gemeint war: Die 'armen Schweine' lässt man nicht alt werden, sie werden sehr jung geschlachtet.

Für mich als Deutschen klingt es bizarr, dass man auf Englisch einfach so sagen kann 'I'm older than cars.' Ich hätte nachfragen müssen, um es zu verstehen.

Answer (score 2):

Dein Beispielsatz ist meiner Meinung nach ein Wortspiel, mit dem zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen von "old" angedeutet werden und wobei es vielleicht nicht offensichtlich ist welche gemeint ist:

1. Wenn ich z.B. sage "I am older than you", dann ist gemeint, dass ich länger gelebt habe als du.
2. Wenn ich aber sage "steam engines are older than cars" (in dieser Bedeutung wird meist der Plural, eine unbestimmte Form oder sonstige Massenbezeichnung verwendet), dann ist gemeint, dass es Dampfmaschinen gab, bevor die Autos erfunden worden sind. Es geht hier nicht unbedingt darum, dass einzelne Dampfmaschinen älter sind oder länger existiert haben als einzelne Autos. Bemerke, dass wenn ich in diesem Satz den Singular in bestimmter Form verwende ("the steam engine is older than the car"), dann habe ich wieder die erste Bedeutung.

Beide Bedeutungen lassen sich übrigens wortwörtlich idiomatisch übersetzen. "Ich bin älter als du" und "Dampfmaschinen sind älter als Autos" sind verständliche, eindeutige deutsche Sätze.

Jetzt machst du aber einen Vergleich zwischen einem bestimmten Objekt ("I") und einer Massenbezeichnung ("cars"), was vielleicht besser auf Englisch geht als auf Deutsch. Wenn ich es genauer überlege, klingen vergleiche wie "X ist/sind ... als Y" meist nur dann flüssig, wenn entweder zwei konkrete Objekte oder zwei Massenbezeichnungen/Konzepte miteinander verglichen werden.

Ich würde also deinen Satz nicht wortwörtlich ins Deutsche übersetzen, sondern umschreiben. Ralf Joerres hat ja schon ein paar Beispiele genannt.

Comment: Ich vermute, Du hast einen kritischen Punkt getroffen: Im Deutschen lassen sich Individuen und Klassen (generalisiert zu verstehende Substantive) nicht in dieser Form unmittelbarer Gegenüberstellung vergleichen. Überhaupt scheint es mir so zu sein, dass ein 'Vor-langer-Zeit-existiert-Haben' einer Klasse am einfachsten mit 'es gab' ausgedrückt wird: Im Paläozoikum gab es noch keine Saurier. Vgl.: Ötzi war älter als das Schwert, aber nicht älter als Pfeil und Bogen. Das müsste umformuliert werden: Zu Ötzis Lebzeiten gab es noch keine Schwerter, aber schon lange vor ihm Pfeil und Bogen.

Answer (score 1):

Dein Beispielsatz gefällt mir nicht recht, das erste Auto wurde 1885 erfunden, da dürfte heute kaum noch jemand mit Recht behaupten können, älter zu sein.

> Ich bin älter als der Personal-Computer

macht es relativ klar, dass wenn grade kein Computer in der Nähe ist ("der" also ein Demonstrativpronomen ist), auf den man sich beziehen kann, das *Konzept* des Computers gemeint ist.

Meine Töchter pflegen mir regelmäßig klarzumachen, dass ich "älter als das Handy" sei.

Comment: Ohne näheres über die Figur in dem Roman zu wissen, gebe ich zu bedenken, dass die Möglichkeit besteht, dass der Roman z.B. im Jahr 1930 spielt, wo jemand, der älter als 45 ist, jetzt nicht sooo ungewöhnlich wäre. Zweite Möglichkeit: Der Roman spielt in der Gegenwart, und der Titelheld kann durch eine Besonderheit in seinem Erbgut nicht altern. Er hat schon unter Cäsar als Legionär gedient, hat gegen Attila gekämpft, lebte 380 Jahre lang in einem Kloster, segelte mit Columbus nach Amerika usw.

Comment: Du hast meine Frage missverstanden. Es geht darin um "ein Wesen, das schon existiert hat, bevor es Autos gab". Das kann ganz offensichtlich kein Mensch sein. Hab meine Frage etwas ergänzt.

Answer (score 0):

»Ich bin älter als Autos« bedeutet im Deutschen so viel wie »Ich bin älter als das erstgebaute Auto« und damit genau das, was du vom Englischen sagst.

Im Roman müsstest du lediglich dafür sorgen, dass die Aussage ernst genommen und nicht als Selbstironie gedeutet wird wie bei dem folgenden Beispiel, bei dem ein 40-Jähriger eine 18-Jährige anspricht und schließlich nach seinem Alter gefragt wird.

> »– – – Wie alt sind Sie eigentlich?«
>   »Ich bin älter als Autos.«

Er hätte auch sagen können »Ich könnte dein Opa sein« oder »Seit Dienstag ist mein Enkel fünfundneunzig«.